# Avoid mutation in this example in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, mutation

Coming from an OO background, I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to solve simple issues with FP when trying to avoid mutation.

```
let mutable run = true
let player1List = ["he"; "ho"; "ha"]

let addValue lst value =
    value :: lst

while run do
    let input = Console.ReadLine()
    addValue player1List input |> printfn "%A"
    if player1List.Length > 5 then 
        run <- false
        printfn "all done" // daz never gunna happen
```

I know it is ok to use mutation in certain cases, but I am trying to train myself to avoid mutation as the default.  With that said, can someone please show me an example of the above w/o using mutation in F#?

The final result should be that player1List continues to grow until the length of items are 6, then exit and print 'all done'

Comment: BTW: Your code does not actually work. You need `run <- false` and also `addValue` should mutate the `player1List` and store the new value (otherwise you just print it and then ignore it).

Comment: thanks, that was a type, i changed to <- ... the addValue was meant to be like that for an example since my goal was to avoid mutation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use recursion

```
open System
let rec makelist l = 
    match l |> List.length with
    |6  -> printfn "all done"; l
    | _ -> makelist ((Console.ReadLine())::l)

makelist []
```

I also removed some the `addValue` function as it is far more idiomatic to just use `::` in typical F# code.

Your original code also has a common problem for new F# coders that you use `run = false` when you wanted `run <- false`.  In F#, `=` is always for comparison.  The compiler does actually warn about this.

Comment: haha, yea, that = vs <- was just a typo, for my quick proto since I never reached that line, i never saw the fail.
Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 4):

As others already explained, you can rewrite imperative loops using recursion. This is useful because it is an approach that always works and is quite fundamental to functional programming.

Alternatively, F# provides a rich set of library functions for working with collections, which can actually nicely express the logic that you need. So, you could write something like:

```
let player1List = ["he"; "ho"; "ha"]
let player2List = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine())
let listOf6 = Seq.append player1List list2 |> Seq.take 6 |> List.ofSeq
```

The idea here is that you create an infinite lazy sequence that reads inputs from the console, append it at the end of your initial `player1List` and then take first 6 elements.

Depending on what your actual logic is, you might do this a bit differently, but the nice thing is that this is probably closer to the logic that you want to implement...

Answer (score 2):

In F#, we use recursion to do loop. However, if you know how many times you need to iterate, you could use F# [List.fold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx) like this to hide the recursion implementation.

```
[1..6] |> List.fold (fun acc _ -> Console.ReadLine()::acc) []
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the pipe from match for readability but use it in the last expression to avoid extra brackets:

```
open System

let rec makelist l = 
    match List.length l with
    | 6 -> printfn "all done"; l
    | _ -> Console.ReadLine()::l |> makelist

makelist []
```